# Missing battery icon in system tray in KDE

Tags: battery, kde, arch-linux

I've just installed arch linux on my laptop. Now i miss the battery icon on system tray. I can't google the anything that would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a battery meter on any panel or desktop.  Click the "Foot" or "Peanut" icon where you want it to appear, and select the battery widget from the list.